# how to find hadoop distribution and version

Tags: hadoop

I have installed hadoop on vmware using centos now I want to find which hadoop distribution and version in hadoop .

When I am typing hadoop version in console I am getting

> Hadoop 1.0.4 Subversion
>   https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r
>   1393290 Compiled by hortonfo on Wed Oct  3 05:13:58 UTC 2012 From
>   source with checksum fe2baea87c4c81a2c505767f3f9b71f4

So I am confused which hadoop distribution I am using.

Comment: Your hadoop version is 1.0.4.

Comment: **"Compiled by hortonfo"** indicates that your distribution is HortonWorks and version is 1.0.4

Answer (score 4):

My Hadoop run on Ubuntu and when I type "hadoop version" in console it shows below:

```
Hadoop 2.4.0
Subversion http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1583262
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-03-31T08:29Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 375b2832a6641759c6eaf6e3e998147
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.4.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

For version details you can visit namenode-ip:50070 and look for **Version:** it will give you the Hadoop version

Note the First three numbers are Hadoop version In my case values is

```
2.5.0-cdh5.3.0, f19097cda2536da1df41ff6713556c8f7284174d
```

So hadoop version is **2.5.0** and distribution is **CDH** whose version is 5.3.0